# Is there a way to persist a Gist settings - spaces vs. tabs, wraps vs. no wrap? How?

Tags: github, settings, gist

Every time I come back to edit a Gist on Github.com, the settings fall back to defaults.

1. Is there a way to persists these for a Gist? How?
2. Can these be configured across all my existing and new Gists? For example, my preference is 4 spaces in place of tabs and soft wrap.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be any Gist dedicated preferences.

You would need to make your own (GitHub) Markdown editor in order to:

- have your own setting
- [Create](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#create-a-gist) or [Edit](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#edit-a-gist) a Gist through GitHub API.

That is obviously not a good or practical option.